# MySQL Select lowercase column name but return uppercase column name for information_schema table in version 8

Tags: php, mysql

in MySQL 5.7 if I query `SELECT index_name, non_unique FROM information_schema.statistics` I will get lowercase column name.

[image]

in MySQL 8.0.14, if I do same query, MySql will return uppercase column name:
[image]

I try a couple case type in the query. in v5.7, MySQL will return case of column name by the case what you type. However, v8.0.14, MySQL return only uppercase column name whatever you type.

Due to my task is upgrade database for Third Party PHP system(SugarCRM), I cannot change any core code of system(the source code use all lowercase column name to get the data). is there any way to resolve this by change configuration of MySQL. or this is just a bug?

Comment: I don't know of a way to fix this in MySQL, but what is stopping you from changing your PHP view to lowercase everything first?

Comment: The case of characters is something that should be handed in presentation layer as @TimBiegeleisen suggested

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because I cannot change core code because it's three party application.